# getting the corresponding div on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` and the corresponding anchor tag inside a while loop. What I want is that when I click on the anchor tag, only the correponding div should be displayed. The problem is that it is only showing the first div of the loop. Please help me to solve the issue.
Here is my code

```
int i=0;
while(i<5){
  <div class="scroll_div04b1" align="center" id="chk">
    <a href="#" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { contentId: 'highslide-0' } )">
      <img src="images/buttons/chk.gif" border="0" />  
    </a>
    <div class="highslide-html-content" id="highslide-0">
    --------
    -------
    </div>
  </div>
  i++
}
```

Now how i will get the `highslide-0 div` corresponding to each image click, `highslide-0 div` is a popup window.
    Please Help.

Comment: Can you do a JSFiddle ?

Comment: I dont know about JSFiddle

Comment: @user1891823 http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am getting value from database and wanting show in a div,ok.After that one href link is there corresponding to div.Since it is inside while loop div is executing several times and also href link.then i want is when i click on href link then only corresponding div should be open..

Comment: are they all in the scroll_div04b1? why are you going for an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('.highslide-html-content').hide();
   $(this).next().show();
});
```

this should select all highslide-html-content divs and hide them before showing the next sibling of the clicked anchor. (in this case the div). also the html-snippet you included is not well-formed, you miss a closing div ;)

this is jquery(!) for this to work you'd need to include [jquery](http://www.jquery.com)

here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZx5R/) with jquery. unfortunately i have not used javascript in ages, thus i am unable to make some flat javascript. note that this is, as Andy stated, very resource intensive for the sole purpose of showing the next sibling on click :(

Comment: How i should use this function because i dont know anything abt JQuery

Comment: see the link i included. it is quite easy to understand. read the documentation for more information

Comment: It's probably best not to include jQuery for this alone as it can be done in simple javascript too. The size of jQuery isn't worth it to use once in an application

Comment: @Andy right y'are, i just assumed he would need some more functions, who are faster/easier with jquery. i apolgise

Comment: Now Plz see the code when i click on image the div id highslide-0 should call, it is working but when i click on another image then also highslide-0 div id is coming with prevoius data

Comment: @user1891823 this selects all a tags. then with .click() all click events get caught and the function handles them. for further information please see http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @user1891823 what is not working?? have you included jquery? how could i know what the hell your pc puts out?

Comment: Thanx for the help dont be angree

Comment: @user1891823 i am not angry, i just can't help you if i have no idea what's going on..